# Clicking on the Search button in JFrame should open a search bar

Tags: java, swing, pdf

I am following the below link to view the PDF file.  [Java Swing PDF Viewer](http://seanshou.blogspot.in/2012/10/java-swing-pdf-viewer.html).

Now I need to add a Search button to the `JFrame` (besides to the navigation buttons).  Clicking on that Search button should open a label with a text field. When the client enter the value to that text field then it should perform the search in whole PDF and display the count of matched words below to the text field. I am very new to swing and trying to find the solution from 3 days. But I didn't get the exact solution. It is very urgent to me. Any help is greatly appreciated.

### First Edit:

```
public class PdfViewer extends JPanel {
    private static enum Navigation {
        GO_FIRST_PAGE, FORWARD, BACKWARD, GO_LAST_PAGE, GO_N_PAGE
    }

    private static final CharMatcher POSITIVE_DIGITAL = CharMatcher.anyOf("0123456789");
    private static final String GO_PAGE_TEMPLATE = "%s of %s";
    private static final int FIRST_PAGE = 1;
    private int currentPage = FIRST_PAGE;
    private JButton btnFirstPage;
    private JButton btnPreviousPage;
    private JTextField txtGoPage;
    private JButton btnNextPage;
    private JButton btnLastPage;
    private JButton print;
    private JButton search;
    private PagePanel pagePanel;
    private PDFFile pdfFile;

    public PdfViewer() {
        initial();
    }

    private void initial() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        btnFirstPage = createButton("|<<");
        topPanel.add(btnFirstPage);
        btnPreviousPage = createButton("<<");
        topPanel.add(btnPreviousPage);
        txtGoPage = new JTextField(10);
        txtGoPage.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        topPanel.add(txtGoPage);
        btnNextPage = createButton(">>");
        topPanel.add(btnNextPage);
        btnLastPage = createButton(">>|");
        topPanel.add(btnLastPage);
        
        search = new JButton("search");
        topPanel.add(search);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel viewPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        scrollPane.setViewportView(viewPanel);

        pagePanel = new PagePanel();
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        pagePanel.setPreferredSize(screenSize);
        viewPanel.add(pagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        disableAllNavigationButton();

        btnFirstPage.addActionListener(new PageNavigationListener(Navigation.GO_FIRST_PAGE));
        btnPreviousPage.addActionListener(new PageNavigationListener(Navigation.BACKWARD));
        btnNextPage.addActionListener(new PageNavigationListener(Navigation.FORWARD));
        btnLastPage.addActionListener(new PageNavigationListener(Navigation.GO_LAST_PAGE));
        txtGoPage.addActionListener(new PageNavigationListener(Navigation.GO_N_PAGE));
        
        search.addActionListener(new Action1());
    }
    
    static class Action1 implements ActionListener {        
          public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {  
              JFrame parent = new JFrame();
              JDialog jDialog = new JDialog();
              Label label = new Label("Search: ");
              final JTextField jTextField = new JTextField(10);
              JPanel panel = new JPanel();
              parent.add(panel);
              panel.add(label);
              panel.add(jTextField);
              parent.setVisible(true);
              parent.setSize(800,400);
              parent.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          }
        }   
}
```

This is the code i have modified.The remaining code is same as there in link.With this code i am getting a search button in JFrame.When i click on that button it is opening a window with Search as the labelname and a textfield.So now i am struck up here.When i enter a value to that textfield it should perform the search through the whole pdf with the textfield value and display the count of matched below to that textfield.

### Second Edit :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

import com.google.common.base.CharMatcher;
import com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile;
import com.sun.pdfview.PagePanel;

public class PdfViewer extends JPanel {
    private static enum Navigation {
        GO_FIRST_PAGE, FORWARD, BACKWARD, GO_LAST_PAGE, GO_N_PAGE
    }

    private static final CharMatcher POSITIVE_DIGITAL = CharMatcher.anyOf("0123456789");
    private static final String GO_PAGE_TEMPLATE = "%s of %s";
    private static final int FIRST_PAGE = 1;
    private int currentPage = FIRST_PAGE;
    private JButton btnFirstPage;
    private JButton btnPreviousPage;
    private JTextField txtGoPage;
    private JButton btnNextPage;
    private JButton btnLastPage;
    private JButton print;
    private JButton search;
    private PagePanel pagePanel;
    private static PDFFile pdfFile;

    static String text;

    public PdfViewer() {
        initial();
    }

    private void initial() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        btnFirstPage = createButton("|<<");
        topPanel.add(btnFirstPage);
        btnPreviousPage = createButton("<<");
        topPanel.add(btnPreviousPage);
        txtGoPage = new JTextField(10);
        txtGoPage.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        topPanel.add(txtGoPage);
        btnNextPage = createButton(">>");
        topPanel.add(btnNextPage);
        btnLastPage = createButton(">>|");
        topPanel.add(btnLastPage);

        search = new JButton("search");
        topPanel.add(search);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel viewPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        scrollPane.setViewportView(viewPanel);

        pagePanel = new PagePanel();
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        pagePanel.setPreferredSize(screenSize);
        viewPanel.add(pagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // disableAllNavigationButton();

        search.addActionListener(new Action1());
    }

    private JButton createButton(String string) {
        return new JButton(string);
    }

    class Action1 implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JDialog jDialog = new JDialog(SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(search));
            Label label = new Label("Search: ");
            final JTextField jTextField = new JTextField(10);
            jTextField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // Here perform search in PDF
            text = jTextField.getText();
            search(pdfFile,text);
                    System.out.println("Search for text " + jTextField.getText() + " requested");
                }
            });
            // If you want to react to every change of text in the textfield, you can
            // use a DocumentListener and invoke the search method for all events.
            jTextField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

                @Override
                public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

                }
            });
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            jDialog.add(panel);
            panel.add(label);
            panel.add(jTextField);
            jDialog.pack();
            jDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(search);
            jDialog.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public static void search(PDFFile pdffile2,String text) {
                
                System.out.println("Inside searh" +text);
                System.out.println("Inside Search Page ::::::::" + pdffile2.getNumPages()); //43 pages
                for (int i = 0;i <= pdffile2.getNumPages(); i++) {
                PDFPage pdfPage = pdffile2.getPage(i);
                if(pdfPage.equals(text)) {
                    System.out.println("equal");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Not Equal");
                }
                    
                }
            }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new PdfViewer());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you have so far? Post some code and show us where you are stuck.

Comment: Find a solution to which part?

Comment: Hi Guillaume Polet thanks for giving the reply.I have edited my original question with the code i have tried.Please look into it and hope give me some solution.

Comment: *"It is very urgent to me"*  Voting to close as 'too localized - a specific moment in time'.  Note that your time constraints are none of our concern, and best kept private.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it.

1. Add an `ActionListener` to the textfield (`actionPerformed` will be invoked everytime the user presses "Enter")
2. Add a `DocumentListener` to the textfield (the methods of the DocumentListener will be invoked everytime the text changes in the textfield)

You will still have to implement the search method in your class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

import com.google.common.base.CharMatcher;
import com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile;
import com.sun.pdfview.PagePanel;

public class PdfViewer extends JPanel {
    private static enum Navigation {
        GO_FIRST_PAGE, FORWARD, BACKWARD, GO_LAST_PAGE, GO_N_PAGE
    }

    private static final CharMatcher POSITIVE_DIGITAL = CharMatcher.anyOf("0123456789");
    private static final String GO_PAGE_TEMPLATE = "%s of %s";
    private static final int FIRST_PAGE = 1;
    private int currentPage = FIRST_PAGE;
    private JButton btnFirstPage;
    private JButton btnPreviousPage;
    private JTextField txtGoPage;
    private JButton btnNextPage;
    private JButton btnLastPage;
    private JButton print;
    private JButton search;
    private PagePanel pagePanel;
    private PDFFile pdfFile;

    public PdfViewer() {
        initial();
    }

    private void initial() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        btnFirstPage = createButton("|<<");
        topPanel.add(btnFirstPage);
        btnPreviousPage = createButton("<<");
        topPanel.add(btnPreviousPage);
        txtGoPage = new JTextField(10);
        txtGoPage.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        topPanel.add(txtGoPage);
        btnNextPage = createButton(">>");
        topPanel.add(btnNextPage);
        btnLastPage = createButton(">>|");
        topPanel.add(btnLastPage);

        search = new JButton("search");
        topPanel.add(search);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel viewPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        scrollPane.setViewportView(viewPanel);

        pagePanel = new PagePanel();
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        pagePanel.setPreferredSize(screenSize);
        viewPanel.add(pagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // disableAllNavigationButton();

        search.addActionListener(new Action1());
    }

    private JButton createButton(String string) {
        return new JButton(string);
    }

    class Action1 implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JDialog jDialog = new JDialog(SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(search));
            Label label = new Label("Search: ");
            final JTextField jTextField = new JTextField(10);
            jTextField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    // Here perform search in PDF
                    System.out.println("Search for text " + jTextField.getText() + " requested");
                }
            });
            // If you want to react to every change of text in the textfield, you can
            // use a DocumentListener and invoke the search method for all events.
            jTextField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

                @Override
                public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

                }
            });
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            jDialog.add(panel);
            panel.add(label);
            panel.add(jTextField);
            jDialog.pack();
            jDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(search);
            jDialog.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new PdfViewer());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Guillaume Polet very thanks for giving the reply.I have edited my original question as second edit with the code you suggested.In search method i am using if(pdfPage.equals(text)) means here i am comparing with the pdfPage not with the pdfPage content.How can i compare the text with the pdfPage content.I didn't find any methods to get the content of pdfPage.Once again Thank You Very Much for giving the reply.

Comment: @rupa Stackoverflow is not a place where people will work for you. Do your work and search how to perform that kind of operation. At least google a few things. Once you have found that, if you are still stuck, then post another question on SO (something like "Text search in PDF file is not working"). Cheers

Comment: +1 for `DocumentListener`, in addition to `ActionListener`.